# How to preserve the data types of individual data when split into an array using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For my code, I received a stream of data from a client which are separated by comma and each field is of different data type. Upon receiving, I split them and write into an array. Code as follows:

```
 require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.open('localhost',2000)
time = Time.now.to_i
s.puts(cf,PUB,#{time},001.41011,N,103.76822)
s.close
```

On the eventmachine server, i code as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require './Load2MySQL.rb'

 module EchoServer

   def post_init
     puts "-- someone connected to the echo server!"
   end

   def receive_data data
       loc = Array.new(6)
       loc = data.split(',').to_a     

     wr2db(loc[0], loc[1], loc[2], loc[3], loc[4], loc[5])

   end

   def unbind
     puts "-- someone disconnected from the echo server!"
     close_connection
#     EventMachine::stop_event_loop
   end
 end

 EventMachine::run {
   EventMachine::start_server "0.0.0.0", 2000, EchoServer
 }
```

I discovered that doing so, all the elements in the array will be converted to strings. How can I preserve their data types?

Regards,
New2RoR

Comment: Thats just the nature of TCP communication. everything gets marshalled into well kind of a string and on the other end of the sockets gets unmarshalled as a string. If you want to persist more information about objects, encode as json and then decode as json but even that might not give you 'kind' information. You might have to explicitly pass class information in another array? By the way, how is this related to Rails, curious?

Comment: Do you know beforehand which array element is of which type?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is the use of the [split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) method, which indeed returns an array of strings. The only way would be to send each element's type along the value, or, if you know it already, force the type after the split like so:

```
float_val = loc(5).to_f
```

A third method would be to use [Ruby's CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) to generate and parse the string. It allows you to use field converters that read values and convert them to Floats or Integers if applicable.

Also, I dont think you need to do `loc = Array.new(6)` in Ruby.
Furthermore, if you are using one of the established mysql adapters, you dont really have to worry about typecasting before storing if that is your problem, it will be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to marshal objects before sending over TCP socket. When sending data use `Marshal.dump(data)` and when receiving data use `Marshal.load(data)`. Have a look at [ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html) for more info. Also depending on your application you might be interested in using [Ruby DRB](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html).